# HTML Escape some xml tag using xslt

Tags: xslt

I have some XML like

```
<ITEM><TITLE>Video: High Stakes for <KW>Obama</KW> &amp; Romney</TITLE></ITEM>
```

which I would like to translate to the below XML using XSLT.

```
<ITEM><TITLE>Video: High Stakes for &lt;KW&gt;Obama&lt;/KW&gt; &amp; Romney</TITLE></ITEM>
```

I tried `<xls:copy-of select="./TITLE"/>` but that is not escaping the XML tags. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sorts of questions always attract a lot of competing answers, because the best answer depends on how generalized you need it to be, and that is not clear from your question.

If you want a super-generalised solution, I will leave that to the regular XSLT SO stars. Or you could just search SO for questions which ask how to serialize/ or stringize XML. There are plenty.

I will offer you a very simple but specific solution, for a very narrow interpretation of your question. For this I will assume that:

1. You are just interested in serializing the content of the `TITLE` element.
2. The element children of `TITLE' (such as`KW`) are restricted, in that they have no children and no attributes, and are not in a namespace.

With this interpretation, this input document...

```
<ITEM>
 <TITLE>Video: High Stakes for <KW>Obama</KW> &amp; Romney</TITLE>
</ITEM>
```

...transformed by this XSLT 1.0 style-sheet (works just the same in 2.0)...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TITLE/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name(),'&gt;',.,'&lt;/',name(),'&gt;')" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...yields...

```
<ITEM>
  <TITLE>Video: High Stakes for &lt;KW&gt;Obama&lt;/KW&gt; &amp; Romney</TITLE>
</ITEM>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT doesn't have a specific, direct feature to destruct markup to text (and you have to think well if this is really useful in your case).

**This said, here is a short solution using a tiny C# extension function** (a similar extension function can easily be written for most other PLs and platforms):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/TITLE/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="my:stringize(.)"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <msxsl:script language="c#" implements-prefix="my">
  public string stringize(XPathNavigator doc)
  {
   return doc.OuterXml;
  }
 </msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<ITEM><TITLE>Video: High Stakes for <KW>Obama</KW> &amp; Romney</TITLE></ITEM>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<ITEM>
  <TITLE>Video: High Stakes for &lt;KW&gt;Obama&lt;/KW&gt; &amp; Romney</TITLE>
</ITEM>
```

**Do note**:

1. This solution flattens out to text the whole subtree rooted in a `TITLE` element that is a child of the top element of the XML document -- regardless of depth -- which the other posted answer doesn't.
2. This solution correctly flattens elements with attributes or empty elements -- which the other posted answer  --  doesn't.

Comment: Do you have a similar solution for Java?

Comment: @Learner, I am not a Java programmer, but there should be a similar way to do this in Java.